# Better solution to overcome Connection reset by peer error in python telnet lib?

Tags: python, linux, telnet, telnetlib

```
> retry = range(3) 
> for attempt in retry:
         try:
>            try:
>                tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
>            except exception  as e:
>                 log error
> 
>             firing cmd
>             break    
          except Exception as e: 
>               log error    
>         finally:
>               telnet close
```

Is the best way or how many times i can retry in telnet lib.best way need.

Comment: It isn't clear what question you are asking, and it is possible that you are asking the wrong question (see "[XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)". Can you describe how and why you are getting "connection reset by peer" errors?

Comment: TO solve telnet - connection reset by peer ERROR...I am trying to retry the connection 3 times...its right solution??